# I am having BAD_ACCESS error - Is my memory allocation understand correct

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks, nsdata, exc-bad-access

So here is what I am trying to do

```
@implementation someHelper

+(BOOL) GetInfo:(NSData **)info1, (NSString**) info2
{
   __block _Bool out = NO;

    //do stuff to get input

    [[Bool result] startSession:input callsBack:^(Abc obj, Bool status)
    {
        if(status)
        {
            *info1 = [obj.Data1 subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2);
            *info2 = obj.string1;
            out = true;
        }
        else
        out = false;
   }];
   return out
}
```

Calling looks something like

```
NSString *a;
NSData   *b;
output = [someHelper GetInfo:(NSData **)&a (NSString **)&b];
```

I think the thing I am missing here is the actual memory allocation for `info1` and `info2`. I am very new to Obj C and it is not clear to me what I need to do for proper allocation.

When I try with

```
 NSMutableData *info1 = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: 2];
 *info1 = [obj.Data1 subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2);
```

I get
    `Assigning to NSMutableData from incompatible type NSData`.

Can someone please help me understand this better and how I can fix the issues?

Answer (score 0):

More likely than not `startSession:callsBack:` is an *asynchronous* method that returns immediately.   In the callback block, you should pass the string and data off to whatever is interested in the updated values.

Given how far from the Objective-C standard your naming conventions and coding patterns are, I would suggest also taking a refresher on how to use Objective-C.

Comment: Other than NSError, what other foundation types get dereferenced in typical code?  Hardly any.   I don't understand why there'd be any reason to pass NSData by reference here.

Comment: @stevesliva Beyond no reason, it simply isn't going to work.  Since `startSession:callsBack:` is (most likely) asynchronous, by the time the block executes, `GetInfo` has already returned and trying to set those inout parameters is utterly pointless.